# Calculating form with javascript using different buttons

Tags: javascript, html, forms, checkbox, radio-button

i am new to html and js. I have created a form with the following script. i have an event handler for calculateTime. I cant seem to get the form to calculate. If you guys could point me in the right direction that would be great. Thanks

```
<script>
function getWaterSystem() {
    var waterSystem;
    var selectedSystem = 0;

    for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
        waterSystem = document.getElementById("system + i");
        if (waterSystem.checked == true) {
            waterSystem = waterSystem(i).value;
        }
    }
    return waterSystem;
}
function largePlant() {
    var checkbox;

    checkbox = document.getElementById("large");
    if (checkbox(i).checked) {
        checkbox = 1.5;
    }
    else {
        checkbox = "";
    }
    return checkbox;
}
function getSoilType() {
    var soilType;
    var selectedSoil = 0;

    for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        soilType = document.getElementById("soil + i");
        if (soilType[i].checked) {
            soilType = soilType[i].value;
        }
    }
    return soilType;
}
function calculateTime() {
    var waterTime = getWaterSystem() * getSoilType() * largePlant();
    alert("The recommended watering time is " + waterTime);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some adjustment, just check it out, it's quite simple:
    document.getElementById("check1").checked

```
<script>
    function getWaterSystem() {
        var waterSystem=0;
        var selectedSystem = 0;

        for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {

            if (document.getElementById("system" + i).checked) {
                reutrn waterSystem = document.getElementById("system" + i).value;
            }
        }
        return waterSystem;
    }
    function largePlant() {
        var checkbox=0;
        if (document.getElementById("large").checked) {
            checkbox = 1.5;
        }
        else {
            checkbox = 0;
        }
        return checkbox;
    }
    function getSoilType() {
        var soilType=0;
        var selectedSoil = 0;

        for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
            soilType = document.getElementById("soil" + i);
            if (document.getElementById("soil" + i). checked) {
                soilType = document.getElementById("soil" + i).value;
                return soilType;
            }
        }
        return soilType;
    }
    function calculateTime() {
        var waterTime = getWaterSystem() * getSoilType() * largePlant();
        alert("The recommended watering time is " + waterTime);
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could it have something to do with these two lines:

```
waterSystem = document.getElementById("system + i");

soilType = document.getElementById("soil + i");
```

If you want to target the id of #systemX or #soilX where X is being a number from you i var. You should write it like this:

```
waterSystem = document.getElementById("system" + i);

soilType = document.getElementById("soil" + i);
```

Comment: I have tried your suggestion but it came up with a syntax error.